# OpenCsv CsvToBeanBuilder not build bean

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a problem with OpenCsv, I load a csv to my webservice with a POST API but if I try to convert the csv to a bean with CsvToBeanBuilder the results beans have all field with null value

This is the API code

```
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> insertPointOfInterest(@RequestAttribute(name="municipalityId", required = true) Long municipalityId,
                                                           @RequestPart("file") FilePart file, @RequestParam Optional<String> languages) throws IOException{
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> errors = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("test", file.filename());

        AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        DataBufferUtils.write(file.content(), channel, 0)
                .subscribe();

        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.filename());

        if (!extension.equals("csv")) {
            result.put("success", false);
            result.put("error", "File non in formato csv");
            return Mono.just(result).log();
        }


        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(tempFile.toFile())))) {

            CsvToBean<PointOfInterestCsv> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(PointOfInterestCsv.class)
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .build();

            List<PointOfInterestCsv> poiCsv = csvToBean.parse();

            extracted(municipalityId, errors, poiCsv, getFirstLanguage(languages).orElse(defaultLanguage));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result.put("success", false);
            result.put("error", ex);
            return Mono.just(result).log();
        } finally {
            Files.deleteIfExists(tempFile);
        }
        result.put("success", true);
        result.put("error", errors);
        return Mono.just(result).log();
    }
```

and this is my bean

```
public class PointOfInterestCsv implements Serializable{

    @CsvBindByName(column = "IDENTIFICATIVO")
    String identificativo;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TITOLO")
    String titolo;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "DESCRIZIONE")
    String descrizione;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "INDIRIZZO")
    String indirizzo;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "CATEGORIA")
    String categoria;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "FILTRO_TERRITORIALE")
    String filtro_territoriale;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TARGET")
    String target;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TAG")
    String tag;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "POI")
    String poi;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TIPO_STRUTTURA")
    String tipo_struttura;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "STELLE")
    String stelle;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "PREZZO")
    String prezzo;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "PAGAMENTO")
    String pagamento;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TRATTAMENTI")
    String trattamenti;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "SERVIZI")
    String servizi;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TIPO_CUCINA")
    String tipo_cucina;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "ACCESSIBILITA")
    String accessibilita;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TIPO_ESPERIENZE")
    String tipo_esperienze;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "DURATA")
    String durata;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TIPOLOGIA_ESPERIENZE")
    String tipologia_esperienze;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TIPO_EVENTO")
    String tipo_evento;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "IMMAGINI")
    String immagini;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "LATITUDINE")
    String latitudine;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "LONGITUDINE")
    String longitudine;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TELEFONO")
    String telefono;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "FAX")
    String fax;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "MAIL")
    String mail;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "SITO_WEB")
    String sito_web;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "MAIL_2")
    String mail_2;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TRIPADVISOR_LINK")
    String tripAdvisor_link;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "FACEBOOK_LINK")
    String facebook_link;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "INSTAGRAM_LINK")
    String instagram_link;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "TWITTER_LINK")
    String twitter_link;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "YOUTUBE_LINK")
    String youtube_link;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "ORARI_DI_APERTURA")
    String orari_di_apertura;

    public String getIdentificativo(){
        return identificativo;
    }

    public void setIdentificativo(String identificativo){
        this.identificativo = identificativo;
    }

    public String getTitolo(){
        return titolo;
    }

    public void setTitolo(String titolo){
        this.titolo = titolo;
    }

    public String getDescrizione(){
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione){
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getIndirizzo(){
        return indirizzo;
    }

    public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo){
        this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
    }

    public String getCategoria(){
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria){
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getFiltro_territoriale(){
        return filtro_territoriale;
    }

    public void setFiltro_territoriale(String filtro_territoriale){
        this.filtro_territoriale = filtro_territoriale;
    }

    public String getTarget(){
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(String target){
        this.target = target;
    }

    public String getTag(){
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag){
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getPoi(){
        return poi;
    }

    public void setPoi(String poi){
        this.poi = poi;
    }

    public String getTipo_struttura(){
        return tipo_struttura;
    }

    public void setTipo_struttura(String tipo_struttura){
        this.tipo_struttura = tipo_struttura;
    }

    public String getStelle(){
        return stelle;
    }

    public void setStelle(String stelle){
        this.stelle = stelle;
    }

    public String getPrezzo(){
        return prezzo;
    }

    public void setPrezzo(String prezzo){
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }

    public String getPagamento(){
        return pagamento;
    }

    public void setPagamento(String pagamento){
        this.pagamento = pagamento;
    }

    public String getTrattamenti(){
        return trattamenti;
    }

    public void setTrattamenti(String trattamenti){
        this.trattamenti = trattamenti;
    }

    public String getServizi(){
        return servizi;
    }

    public void setServizi(String servizi){
        this.servizi = servizi;
    }

    public String getTipo_cucina(){
        return tipo_cucina;
    }

    public void setTipo_cucina(String tipo_cucina){
        this.tipo_cucina = tipo_cucina;
    }

    public String getAccessibilita(){
        return accessibilita;
    }

    public void setAccessibilita(String accessibilita){
        this.accessibilita = accessibilita;
    }

    public String getTipo_esperienze(){
        return tipo_esperienze;
    }

    public void setTipo_esperienze(String tipo_esperienze){
        this.tipo_esperienze = tipo_esperienze;
    }

    public String getDurata(){
        return durata;
    }

    public void setDurata(String durata){
        this.durata = durata;
    }

    public String getTipologia_esperienze(){
        return tipologia_esperienze;
    }

    public void setTipologia_esperienze(String tipologia_esperienze){
        this.tipologia_esperienze = tipologia_esperienze;
    }

    public String getImmagini(){
        return immagini;
    }

    public void setImmagini(String immagini){
        this.immagini = immagini;
    }

    public String getLatitudine(){
        return latitudine;
    }

    public void setLatitudine(String latitudine){
        this.latitudine = latitudine;
    }

    public String getLongitudine(){
        return longitudine;
    }

    public void setLongitudine(String longitudine){
        this.longitudine = longitudine;
    }

    public String getTelefono(){
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono){
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getFax(){
        return fax;
    }

    public void setFax(String fax){
        this.fax = fax;
    }

    public String getMail(){
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail){
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getSito_web(){
        return sito_web;
    }

    public void setSito_web(String sito_web){
        this.sito_web = sito_web;
    }

    public String getMail_2(){
        return mail_2;
    }

    public void setMail_2(String mail_2){
        this.mail_2 = mail_2;
    }

    public String getTripAdvisor_link(){
        return tripAdvisor_link;
    }

    public void setTripAdvisor_link(String tripAdvisor_link){
        this.tripAdvisor_link = tripAdvisor_link;
    }

    public String getFacebook_link(){
        return facebook_link;
    }

    public void setFacebook_link(String facebook_link){
        this.facebook_link = facebook_link;
    }

    public String getInstagram_link(){
        return instagram_link;
    }

    public void setInstagram_link(String instagram_link){
        this.instagram_link = instagram_link;
    }

    public String getTwitter_link(){
        return twitter_link;
    }

    public void setTwitter_link(String twitter_link){
        this.twitter_link = twitter_link;
    }

    public String getYoutube_link(){
        return youtube_link;
    }

    public void setYoutube_link(String youtube_link){
        this.youtube_link = youtube_link;
    }

    public String getOrari_di_apertura(){
        return orari_di_apertura;
    }

    public void setOrari_di_apertura(String orari_di_apertura){
        this.orari_di_apertura = orari_di_apertura;
    }

    public String getTipo_evento(){
        return tipo_evento;
    }

    public void setTipo_evento(String tipo_evento){
        this.tipo_evento = tipo_evento;
    }
}
```

I'll try to upload this csv file

```
IDENTIFICATIVO;TITOLO;DESCRIZIONE;INDIRIZZO;CATEGORIA;FILTRO_TERRITORIALE;TARGET;TAG;POI;TIPO_STRUTTURA;STELLE;PREZZO;PAGAMENTO;TRATTAMENTI;SERVIZI;TIPO_CUCINA;ACCESSIBILITA;TIPO_ESPERIENZE;DURATA;TIPOLOGIA_ESPERIENZE;TIPO_EVENTO;IMMAGINI;LATITUDINE;LONGITUDINE;TELEFONO;FAX;MAIL;SITO WEB;MAIL 2;TRIPADVISOR LINK;FACEBOOK LINK;INSTAGRAM LINK;TWITTER LINK;YOUTUBE LINK;ORARI DI APERTURA
1;;Evento prova;via xxx;Eventi;Comune;Altro;Spettacoli/Eventi;altro INT. TUR;;;Prezzo economico ;;;;;Disabili;;2h;;Concerti;;10.12;11.45;123;21;prova@prova.it;https://www.google.com;;;;;;;;
```

and this is the result afer parse

[image]

I've also tried to send only one field in the csv (obviously modifying the bean) and to modify the data types related to the fields "identificativo", "latitudine" and "longitudine", setting them respectively to Integer and Double, but the result is not changed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it in this way:

Change the Reader type from this:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(tempFile.toFile())))
```

to this:

```
Reader targetReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(targetReader);
```

So, I think, in your case, you have to convert your file to an InputStream and use `CSVReader` instead `InputStreamReader`.